# Exporting a Parallel Foreach Call Into an Enviornment

Tags: r, foreach, quantmod, parallel.foreach, doparallel

I would like to export the  out puts from foreach into an environment. I am pulling time series data from yahoo finance.

```
library(quantmod)
library(foreach)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores=2)

hub = new.env()
tickers = c("NKE", "AAPL", "MSFT", "TSLA", "MPC", "PEP", "GIS", "MA","V", "CAT", "KHC", "AMZN", "NFLX", "GS", "MS", "BAC", "GE", "KO", "JPM", "AMAT", "ABT", "BIIB")

#I have tried 2 methods below.
#The first gives me a list of just the ticker names.
#The second puts the data into a list. I am looking for an enviornment
foreach(r = tickers, .packages = "quantmod") %dopar% lapply(r, getSymbols, env = hub)

enviro = foreach(r = tickers, .packages = "quantmod")%dopar% lapply(r, getSymbols, auto.assign = F)

class(enviro)
[1] "list"
```

The enviornment should look like this(it works when i do not run it in a foreach loop).

```
hub = new.env()
#the following line of code takes about 1 min. Just a heads up
getSymbols(tickers, env = hub)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is very unclear, but from your question it seems you are trying to combine the outputs into a single environment, to obtain a greater speed.

Now you should likely note a few things. `quantmod::getSymbols` has quite some overhead to each call. With your current method, you should see a loss of performance, due to the function being called for every symbol.

### Optimizations

One method to reduce overhead, is to split each calculation into chunks. The `foreach` package relies on the `iterators` package, which allows one to split up the computations into chunks, quite simply.

```
nworker = 2
registerDoParallel(cores = nworker)
tickers = matrix(c("NKE", "AAPL", "MSFT", "TSLA", "MPC", "PEP", "GIS", "MA","V", "CAT", "KHC", "AMZN", "NFLX", "GS", "MS", "BAC", "GE", "KO", "JPM", "AMAT", "ABT", "BIIB"), ncol = 1)
tickerIter <- iterators::iter(tickers, by = 'row', #I made a 1 column matrix, so i will iterate over each row.
                              chunksize = ceiling(length(tickers)/nworker) #Set chunk size, such that each worker gets 1 job.
)
```

In the code above, `tickerIter` is now an iterator over all the the symbols, with a chunk length of `nworker`. Thus each worker (core) only gets a single chunk, and we will only have to export to and import from each worker once. `tickerIter` will be given as our argument in the `foreach` loop instead of the raw tickers. 
To see how the iterator outputs to the `foreach` loop, you could try executing `nextElem(tickerIter)` which will output one chunk. **Note** however, that you will need to re-assign the iterator, as the chunk will then not be assigned in the `foreach` loop if it has already been output using `nextElem`.

### Combining into environment

From the question you want to combine the output into a single environment. Doing this directly within the `foreach` is simply not possible, at least not without the danger of crashing the R session. Foreach by defaults performs parallization by creating multiple R sessions, exporting data and executing the code/expression provided. Thus you would have to hook into the current R session, and assign the variables to the environment through this hook. This is not recommended.

But `foreach` contains a `.combine` argument, which can be given a custom function to combine. Additionally if the function is made to combine any number of inputs, using the `.multicombine = TRUE` the function will only be executed once with every output.

I don't see why you would want to specifically add them into the hub environment, as such in the code example below, the output is instead combined into a single list. The list could then be converted using `list2env` to export output into a specific environment.

**Note** the use of `tickerIter` instead of the raw tickers.

```
output <- foreach(r = tickerIter, 
                  .combine = function(...){
                    c(...) #Combine all outputs into a list
                  }, 
                  .multicombine = TRUE, 
                  .packages = "quantmod")%dopar% {
                    currenv <- environment() 
                    getSymbols(r, currenv)
                    as.list(currenv)
                  }
#If you really want it in a specific environment, you could use: (Could also be used in .combine)
list2env(output, hub)
```